# Using CSS, how can I make my document expand to the user's viewport if the content doesn't scroll?

Tags: css

I'm having the hardest time understanding how `min-height` is supposed to work. I figured that if I placed it over a wrapping div, that it would expand accordingly.

If your browser is large enough, there is a large space below the footer. I would like it if the footer was touching the bottom of the view port if there isn't much content.

Otherwise, if there is a good amount of content, then the page should obviously scroll accordingly.

My HTML document is set up like this (for the sake of brevity, I've removed all the content and am just showing the nesting structure):

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="top" class="five-box-shadow full-ten-border">
            <div id="header" class="top-ten-radius">
                <div id="logo">
                </div>
                <div id="topbar">
                </div>
            </div>
        <div id="nav" class="bottom-ten-radius">
            <ul id="tabnav">
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="clearer"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="wrapper" class="full-ten-border five-box-shadow">
            <div id="content" class="full-ten-border">
                <div id="main"></div>
                <div id="secondary"></div>
                <div class="clearer"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer" class="bottom-ten-radius"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

And the accompanying CSS that I thought would work:

```
#container {
    width: 880px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    /*margin-top: 5px;*/
    min-height:100%;

}
```

Now, if I change `#container` to have `height: 100%`, it will stretch down but it will go too far and create scroll bars.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically the extra space is the result of padding/margins on the body and html tags (often browsers add it automatically).

```
html,body {height:100%;padding:0;margin:0}
```

Inner objects with height 100% + margins/padding can still push this out so you'll have to be vigilant or use overflow:hidden somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

`min-height` simply sets the minimum height that the div can be reduced to by the user,

I referred someone to this earlier this is just what you need to set it to the browsers bottom with little content:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want your footer to always sit at the bottom of the page?

You can achieve this by assigning the following style to your **footer ID**:

```
#footer{
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
}
```

You may have to add some other styling but that should get you on your way.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, that wasn't what I intended. I worded my question poorly. I meant more that the div will expand to the bottom of the page and fill the viewport even if there is a lack of content. If there is enough content to scroll the page, then it should scroll normally.

Comment: Gottcha. Have you tried setting the HTML and Body to 100% and then setting the #container to min-height:100%, height:100% ?

Comment: Also, the link to your site doesn't seem to be in your question anymore - are you able to put it back up there for people to take a look?